# I'm not sure if I have correctly converted a string to an integer?

Tags: python, string, integer

I apologize if this post isn't formatted correctly, I've tried to make sure that it is but this is my first time posting so I imagine I may have gotten something wrong.

I'm a complete beginner learning Python 3 and am going through a Udemy course where currently we are learning about joins and splits.

A challenge was set to convert a string of numbers to integers. The code I have written returns the values as individual numbers, however I am not sure whether these values were converted to integers or still are strings? The instructor of the course did not use the method that I have below and his method returned a list of integers.

I used the isdigit() method to see whether or not 'digits' returned True which it did. However I feel as though I've gone wrong somewhere?

I imagine this is an extremely basic question but any sort of clarity would be greatly appreciated!

```
numbers = "9,223,372,036,854,775,807"

for digits in numbers.split(","):
    print(int(digits))
```

Comment: If you just want to have a look at those numbers, this is a perfect code.

Comment: It doesn't matter if they are are ints or strings when you print them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are outputting numbers.

If you want to output a list of numbers, you can achieve it in two ways.

1. create an empty list and push number into it.

   ```
   numbers = "9,223,372,036,854,775,807"
   ans = []
   for digits in numbers.split(","):
       ans.append(int(digits))
   print(ans)
   ```
2. use list comprehension.

   ```
   numbers = "9,223,372,036,854,775,807"
   print([int(element) for element in numbers.split(",")])
   ```

Comment: thanks for this, just to confirm then that I have successfully converted a string into integers?

Comment: To make sure you have try adding it to another number :).

Comment: @JamieMiles, yes the individual outputted instances are integers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative to @Bryan Deng's answer:

```
num = '123,456,789'
num = num.replace(',', '') # replaces all commas with a '' empty string
# This way we don't have to convert to list than back to string

print(num) 
# 123456789
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're asking to convert numbers from a string to an int using splits and joins. Here's one way to do it:

```
numbers = "123,456,789"

numbers.split(",") # numbers is now a list -> ["123", "456", "789"]
"".join(numbers) # converts numbers back into a string -> "123456789"

print(int(numbers))
# >>> 123456789
```